# Как открыть полную таблицу вместе с зависимостями в ms_sql_server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Как здесь:

[image]

*Текст для заполнения минимально длины*

Answer (score 1):

Подключите к серверу ваш акцесс, там и откроете. Альтернатива - написать соответствующий запрос.